# Unknown NullReferenceException in C# with class references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I read this [explanation of NullReferenceException in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but couldn't find an answer.

I'm working in Unity5 (2D) and trying to make a button that, when clicked, activates a method in the script of another object.

**In the classes, I added comments like //(line #) so you can reference from the NRE easier.**

```
public class runePadController : MonoBehaviour {
public void shoot() {
    var fccClass = new friendlyCastleController();
    fccClass.shoot(); //(Line 23)
}
}
```

The button activates the shoot() method in the above class.

```
public class friendlyCastleController : MonoBehaviour {
public void shoot() {
    useElement (true, "fireBall"); //(Line 36)
}

public void useElement (bool atk, string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "fireBall":
            if (atk)
            {
                //Object clone;
                Vector3 nPosition = new Vector3();
                float nX = transform.position.x + Random.Range(-5F, 5F); //(Line 48)
                float nY = transform.position.y + 3F;
                nPosition.Set(nX, nY, 0);

                Quaternion nAngle = new Quaternion();
                nAngle.Set(Random.Range(-0.15F, 0.15F), 1, 0, 0);
                //Debug.Log(nPosition + " :: " + nAngle);

                //clone = (Instantiate(fireBallPF, nPosition, nAngle)) as GameObject;
                Instantiate(fireBallPF, nPosition, nAngle);
            }
            else
            {

            }

            break;
        default:
           Debug.Log ("Error: Default Switch Called in FriendlyCastleController");
            break;
    }
}
```

...and this is part of the class which deals with the called method.

However, Unity throws this at me:

```
NullReferenceException
friendlyCastleController.useElement (Boolean atk, System.String type) (at Assets/Scripts/friendlyCastleController.cs:48)
friendlyCastleController.shoot () (at Assets/Scripts/friendlyCastleController.cs:36)
runePadController.shoot () (at Assets/Scripts/runePadController.cs:23)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:144)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:621)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:756)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

To anyone who understands this better, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks! :)

Comment: we dont know, where is line 48

Comment: Presumably either `transform` is null or `transform.position` is null.

Comment: It says where line 48 is. Look in the code of the second class. :)

Comment: Also, when the method is run within it's own class, it works fine. No idea why the transform would be null.

Comment: this is completely wrong: friendlyCastleController.  It must be FriendlyCastleController.  Same for your other class names.

Comment: "var fccClass = new FriendlyCastleController();"  You would not call the variable "fccClass".  (Would a parent name their child "John" or "JohnPerson" ?)  the variable name would typically be simply friendlyCastleController (identical to the class name, but, with lower-case first letter).  You need to change all this.

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the `friendlyCastleController` class to the gameObject from where you are taking transform.position values, and in `runePadController` instead for creating a `new friendlyCastleController` use,

```
var fccClass = gameObjectName.getComponent<friendlyCastleController>();
```

---

OP, everything you are doing is **completely wrong**:

This statement

```
 var fccClass = new FriendlyCastleController();
```

is completely meaningless and ***does not exist*** in Unity.  Unity ***is not*** an OO system, it is an ECS system.  There ***is no*** inheritance nor any OO concepts whatsoever.  This line

```
 public class FriendlyCastleController:MonoBehaviour
```

means that `FriendlyCastleController` is ***a MonoBehavior***. What does that mean? It means it is a *component* you *attach to* an actual specific *GameObject*.

It ***can not exist on its own***, it can ***only exist as an attachment to a game object***.

1. in the editor make a new game object (perhaps a small cube for example) called AAA
2. actually attach a `FriendlyCastleController` script to that object
3. make a new script called Test.cs, also a monobehavior, and attach Test.cs to some other object called BBB
4. In Test.cs, do this

   ```
     public FriendlyCastleController friendlyCastle;
   ```
5. Now LOOK in the Editor at BBB.  Notice you can actually ***drag to the slot*** "friendlyCastle".  Do that - in fact drag ***from AAA***.

Now you understand how Unity works.

in RunePadController you *must* have a

```
      public FriendlyCastleController friendlyCastle;
```

and you drag your "AAA" object (in the example here) to that.  Later, you can learn how to "Find" the "AAA" object on the fly inside RunePadController.

Comment: Indeed.  I will expand on your answer.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you for the thorough explanation sir.

Comment: I entered "public FriendlyCastleController friendlyCastle;" in to the RunePadController, and it seems to already know the class. I can't select it in Unity, but that may be because of an error. You said "gameObjectName" at the top of your answer, so I assume it is meant to be the the friendlyCastle object, the physical object in Unity with the class attached to it. However, it says "FriendlyCastleController does not contain a definition for 'getComponent' and no extension method 'getComponent' in "var fccClass = friendlyCastle.getComponent<FriendlyCastleController>();".

Comment: Have you assigned the RunePadController to a gameObject, if so check that gameObject's inspector view, you will see a place by the name `friendly Castle` where you can drag and drop the physical Object (Gameobject which contain the `FriendlyCastleController`) on to. doing so now you do not need to use `var fccClass = friendlyCastle.getComponent<FriendlyCastleController>();` you can remove that line of code and directly use friendlyCastle variable in the place of fccClass as `friendlyCastle.shoot();`

Comment: Please tick as correct if this was to answer you expected.